# NCWidgetDisplayMode not set to .expanded in iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift3, today-extension, ios10-today-widget

I know this type of question has been asked before, but none of them is able to solve my problem.

I want to set the Today's Extension height to be variable.

For this I have included the below code as suggested in related posts:

```
override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if #available(iOSApplicationExtension 10.0, *)
        {
            self.extensionContext?.widgetLargestAvailableDisplayMode = .expanded
        }
        else
        {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
    }

@available(iOSApplicationExtension 10.0, *)
    func widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange(_ activeDisplayMode: NCWidgetDisplayMode, withMaximumSize maxSize: CGSize)
    {
        if activeDisplayMode == .expanded
        {
            preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 200.0)
        }
        else
        {
            preferredContentSize = maxSize
        }
    }
```

The problem I am facing is, even after setting `widgetLargestAvailableDisplayMode` to `.expanded` in `viewDidLoad`, when the protocol method `widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange` is called, it is still giving me the `activeDisplayMode` as `.compact`.

What else need to be done to make the widget work right in iOS 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

Actually when the widget is loaded for the first time, it is by default in the `compact` mode and so `widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange`  is called with `activeDisplayMode` as `.compact`.

After loading,

1. When **Show More** button is pressed, `widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange`  is called with `activeDisplayMode` as `.expanded`.
2. When **Show Less** button is pressed, `widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange`  is called with `activeDisplayMode` as `.compact`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm tempted to edit the question, but the core of the problem that lead you to ask is: `var widgetActiveDisplayMode: NCWidgetDisplayMode { get }`